# Mocking component function for the purposes of component integration test in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, mocking, integration-testing, qunit

Let'a assume a simple EmberJS component:

```
//my-app/components/my-component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({

  classNames: ['cursor-pointer'],

  doSth(){
      // whatever, state of the component does not change
  },

  clickListener: Ember.on('click', function(){
      this.doSth();
  })
});
```

Now I would like to use integration tests to find out whether clicking the component reaches (delegates to) the `doSth()` method.

```
moduleForComponent('my-component', 'Integration | Component | stores parser previewer', {
  integration: true
});
test('should call doSth() on click', function (assert) {

   /* Line 3 - the place I tried to set mocked doSth() up */      

   this.render(hbs`{{my-component}}`);
   this.$('.cursor-pointer').click(); // triggers clickListener() correctly
});
```

The problem is that I cannot substitute method `doSth()` with my mock.
Thus I never run into `assert.ok()` statement.

I have tried to insert following statements onto the line 3 in the test:

```
// idea 1
this.set('doSth', function(){
    assert.ok(true);
  });

// idea 2
this.doSth = function(){
   assert.ok(true);
};
```

None of the 2 approaches (idea 1, idea 2) worked. `this.subject()` is also unavailable since it's an integration test, not a unit test.

**Update:**
Imagine `doSth()` be a function like the openUrlInANewTab() shown below that does not influence the component's state, nor the associated controller's nor route's state.
Example:

```
//my-app/components/my-component.js
... 
import openUrlInANewTab from 'my-app/utils/new-tab-opener'; 
... 
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  ...
  doSth(url){ 
     openUrlInANewTab(url); 
  }
```

while

```
// my-app/utils/new-tab-opener.js
export default function openUrlInANewTab(){
      anchor = document.createElement("a");
      ...
      anchor.click();
      ...
}
```

Comment: would something like [this](https://github.com/elwayman02/ember-sinon-qunit) help?

Comment: In the [Usage](https://github.com/elwayman02/ember-sinon-qunit#usage) section the example relies on `const route = this.subject();` followed by `const stub = this.stub(route, 'transitionTo');`. Since I am not allowed to use `this.subject()`, the problem preserves. I tried to use it directly upon this as follows: `const stub = this.stub(this, 'doSth')`; but I am getting following error: `Cannot stub non-existent own property doSth`

Comment: if `component.doSth` does something to the controller or to your route, you can test whether or not *that thing* happens; if you want to check if the click successfully executes the `doSth` function then I don't know if this particular test should be in integration

Comment: that's the thing. Thus I mentioned that  *state of the component does not change*, because it's a method that calls function that creates an anchor element and clicks it. Something completely unrelated to the component or the controller/route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move `doSth` to service `custom-service` that you inject to your `my-component`. Then in test you can EASILY test this by injecting fake service.

tests/integration/components/my-component-test.js:

```
test('should call doSth() on click', function(assert) {
  const customStub = Ember.Service.extend({
    doSth() {
      // whatever, state of the component does not change
      console.log('Stubbed doSth fired');
      assert.ok(true, 'Stubbed doSth fired');
    }
  });
  this.register('service:custom-service', customStub);
  this.inject.service('custom-service', { as: 'customService' });
  this.render(hbs`{{my-component}}`);
  this.$('.cursor-pointer').click(); // triggers clickListener() correctly
});
```

components/my-component.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  customService: Ember.inject.service('custom-service'),
  classNames: ['cursor-pointer'],

  clickListener: Ember.on('click', function(){
    this.get('customService').doSth();
    console.log('Click listener');
  })
});
```

- [Working demo.](https://ember-twiddle.com/35c52e2893a686ff1ba3bb2143fa1bd9?fileTreeShown=false&openFiles=tests.integration.components.my-component-test.js%2C)
- [Ember Guides.](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/testing/testing-components/#toc_stubbing-services)

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to implement a service just for this purpose since the `doSth()` function needs to keep no state, since it's more a utility thing. However, it seems this is the way to go in my case, because the logic might be shared among more components (although sharing no single state). What is more, `doSth()` logic should be completely independent from the component's context and thus solution proposed by @alptugd would break the design a bit. I've updated my post so that the situation is clear to everyone and I'm accepting your answer as long as there is no perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to what Daniel had proposed you might consider using a closure action in case of handling click within your component. What I mean is instead of delegating to one of your methods (what you had done and could not test) or to a service (what Daniel suggested) just trigger an action passed to your component. This way also provides you the opportunity to mock in your test. Moreover, this approach results in a more reactive component; since you inject the behavior to your component from the owner at runtime; which enables you to reuse your custom component within different contexts (different parent components/templates) easily. See the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a83b5c1655f40beb42f66388950e529d?openFiles=tests.integration.components.my-component-test.js%2C) for an example of what I mean.

Comment: Your answer would work, however, it would break the concept of keeping the component click action isolated (this highly depends on the situation I am facing though). I am already notifying component's parent in a specific case, and so I know and test such pattern, however, `doSth()` has nothing to do with parent's state nor behavior. I am voting your answer up because it might help in several cases, by now is it not the solution I would be 100% satisfied with. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: @Pavol As you mentioned if `doSth()` is totally an internal behaviour that you do not want to expose to the parent; then my suggestion would break encapsulation of your component. As I said it was just an alternative suggestion to the answer provided above. thanks for the question and your relevant comments.